# How to change the font in all FlowDocumentReader controls?

Tags: wpf, fonts, flowdocumentreader

How to change font in all FlowDocumentReader controls in WPF?

For some selection i do

```
FontFamily f = new FontFamily("Verdana");
flowDR.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontFamilyProperty, f);
```

But how can I change the font for the whole document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am ashamed...)

```
FontFamily f = new FontFamily("Calibri_click");
myFlow.FontFamily = f;
```

Where is myFlow = FlowDocument